# how to count number of sheet excel in node js

Tags: node.js, excel

I have an excel file, how can I count total of sheets in that file use node js ?

I use the xlsx library, but in the documentation I did not find to see the total sheets in the file excel

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdullillah, i found xlsx-populate for Get all sheets as an array